# How to permit local standard users to change password? [2008 R2]

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a group of users that can access the server to use some tools and they want to change the password themselves.

How can I permit them?

(for the record I've created a group where all them are in, besides the Users group)

Comment: Users should be able to change their own passwords by default. Are they getting an error message?

Comment: yes, I think the same...

they are getting an "Access is denied" message

Answer (score 0):

'Users' is not a group, it is a container, anyways coming to your question, if you have added your users to a group then set the permission of that group as per your need. For setting permission right click on group, go to properties->security.There you can see permissions and options to apply or deny them.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact error message I can only assume that the password policy on that server (or domain) are set to have either a minimum password age, length or complexity. It the new password doesn't meet those criteria then it won't be allowed to change it.